# What's the geometrical interpretation of the transitive, faithful action of $S_4$ by conjugation on the set of its four Sylow $3$-subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetric-groups, group-actions, sylow-theory

A pair of recent posts ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4048178/870827) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4047833/870827)) have posed the same question: show that the action of the symmetry group of a cube on pairs of opposite faces defines a surjective homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$. There I guessed that this action is the transitive action of $S_4$ by conjugation on the set of its three Sylow $2$-subgroups. Whether or not this identification is correct, this has made me raise the following, "converse" question: what's the geometrical interpretation of the transitive, faithful action of $S_4$ by conjugation on the set of its four Sylow $3$-subgroups? In particular, what are the four "geometrical elements" acted on by the symmetry group of a cube in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cube model, each Sylow 3-subgroup corresponds to a pair of opposite vertices of the cube, more specifically it is the group of rotations around the axis connecting those two vertices. $S_4$ acts by rotation on this set of pairs.